# Spring Framework bean wiring : Can we create multiple beans using same java class in Spring configuration file?

Tags: java, spring

Can we create multiple beans using same java class in Spring configuration file?

```
<beans ....
    <bean name="customeBeanInstance1" class="model.CustomBean">
        <property name="name" value="customBeanOne"/>
    </bean>  
    <bean name="customeBeanInstance2" class="model.CustomBean">
        <property name="name" value="customBeanTwo"/>
    </bean>  > 
</beans>
```

If yes, Then how wiring is going to work?

What is the practical use of such configuration?

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

It is possible of course.  Something to bear in mind (for which I believe caused your confusions):

1. Stereotypes annotations (`@Component`, `@Service`) is NOT the only way to tell Spring to create a bean.  There are other ways, like in XML app context config file.
2. Auto-wiring by type is not the only way Spring inject a bean.  You can explicitly tell Spring which bean to inject by providing bean name etc.

So, what you think may not be possible is in fact quite common with, for example, an XML config like this:

```
<beans>
  <bean id="basicFooService" class="com.foo.FooServiceImpl" />
  <bean id="advancedFooService" class="com.foo.FooServiceImpl" >
      ... different properties
  </bean>

  <bean id="barService" class="com.bar.BarServiceImpl">
    <property name="fooService" ref="advancedFooService" />
  </bean>
</beans>
```